# Can anyone help me find the error in this code made with SFML?

Tags: c++, network-programming, sfml

I wrote this code and when I tried it by using two instances of the program on my own computer(I don't have two at home) it worked, I then tried it at school on different computers and it didn't work, so I tried asking my friends to try it on their computers because the school may have blocked udp packets, they said the code didn't work even though pinging worked.
I tried asking on the SFML forums but haven't got a solution yet and three days have passed.

```
#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include "SFML\Window.hpp"
#include "SFML\Network.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::UdpSocket socket;
    sf::IpAddress thisIp = sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress();
    socket.bind(sf::Socket::AnyPort);
    char clientServerOption;
    cout << "Type 'c' for client and 's' for server"<<endl;
    cin >> clientServerOption;

    if(clientServerOption == 'c')
    { 
        string str;
        cout << "Type the IP address here" << endl;
        cin >> str;
        sf::IpAddress serverIp = sf::IpAddress(str);
        cout << "Type the Server Port here" << endl;
        cin >> str;
        unsigned short serverPort = stoi(str);

        cout << "Send: "; 
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, str, '\n');

        sf::Packet packet;
        packet << str;
        socket.send(packet, serverIp, serverPort);
        socket.receive(packet, serverIp, serverPort);
        packet >> str;
        cout << "Server says: " << str << endl;
    }
    else if(clientServerOption == 's')
    {
        vector <sf::IpAddress> clientIps;
        vector <unsigned short> clientPorts;
        clientIps.push_back(sf::IpAddress());
        clientPorts.push_back(0);
        unsigned short thisPort = socket.getLocalPort();
        cout << "Server hosted with ip " << thisIp << " on port " << thisPort << endl;
        sf::Packet packet;
        socket.receive(packet, clientIps.at(0), clientPorts.at(0));
        string getMessage;
        packet >> getMessage;
        packet.clear();
        cout << getMessage << endl;
        packet << "Message Received";
        socket.send(packet, clientIps.at(0), clientPorts.at(0));
    }

    system("pause");
    
}
```

The includes I didn't use are added for future usage, the same applies for vectors of IPs and Ports.

Comment: There are a lot possible things that can fail. There can be firewalls for example. Can you use a packet sniffer (e.g. Wireshark) on the school computers? That would let you monitor the network traffic and see whether the packet was sent and received at each computer.

Comment: I don't really know how to use it but it should be installed, could you tell me what I should be searching on it for? I tried using it once but there were just so much information traveling that I couldn't understand a thing and just closed it

Comment: I agree it's not the easiest tool to use. The first thing to do is to filter by IP of the other computer you want to connect to. That should leave you with just the packets you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that on Friday since it's the earliest I get access to the lab and then I'll let you know